# How to get a RadioButton's label height - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, radio-button

I want to get radioButton's label height in as3.

I have 5 radio buttons in my radioButton group. One of those radioButtons has a three line label, another has a single line etc...

When I try to access the `radioButton.height`, I always get same value regardless of the label height.

I need to know the height of the label, so I can set the radioButton y coordinate accordingly.

can I change the radioButton's label height?

```
spacing = 30;
rb.label = tempQQString   //from xml. long or short string anyone
rb.group = myGroup;
rb.value = i + 1;

rb.x = answerX;
rb.y = questionField.height + (questionY+20) + (i * spacing); // here use rb.height or rb.textField.height 

trace("rb height**" + rb.height) // always get velue 22;
addChild(rb);
```

Comment: What radio button class are you using? You will not get the radio button label height by `rb.height`, it represent the height of the entire radio button component, the label is a child of radio button it have it's own height.

Comment: Yes, sometimes it's silly that the fl controls like radioButton override the true height so it ignores the label...

Comment: there is no need answer. rb.textField.height is get radioButton's label's height. Thanx :)

Comment: @SerdarAlkan - are you actually using the solution you chose as the answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.

```
for(var i=0;i<rb.numChildren;i++){
    if(rb.getChildAt(i) is TextField){
        var txt:TextField = rb.getChildAt(i) as TextField;
        trace(txt.height+":"+rb.height);//traces the height of text field and radio button 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RadioButton and any fl control that extends labelButton (all the ones that have a label), expose the actual text field with the `.textField` property.

So for your example, instead of using `rb.height`, you would use `rb.textField.height` to get the height of just the label portion of the control.

You can also set properties on the textField as well.

```
rb.textField.background = true;
rb.textField.backgroundColor = 0xDDDDDD;

rb.textField.multiline = true;
rb.textField.wordWrap = true;
rb.textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
```

---

now, **for your scenario**, you may be better off just using the radio button's bounds instead, as it will be the **REAL** height of the object.

```
rb.getBounds(rb).height;  //this will be the true height of the component.
```

If your label was one line and your icon was taller than your label, you could potentially be getting a value from rb.textField.height that is smaller than the real height of the radio button.

Comment: thanx to answer :) i don t know "rb.getBounds(rb).height" code. Nice :)

Comment: Please accept the answer then. This WAY WAY WAY more efficient and clean than looping through every sub element of the radio button until you reach a text field instance.